# ERROR java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate

Tags: java, oracle, api, maven, jersey

I am trying to deploy my REST API on server and keep getting this error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate`

I have checked in the `javax.ws.rs` JAR and found the class `RuntimeDelegate`

I am using

- Java
- Oracle
- Maven
- Jersey

Here is my pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.car.apiproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>carcreation_jdbc</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>carcreation_jdbc</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>carcreation_jdbc</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-bundle-jaxrs</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.16</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Here is the complete stacktrace

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.findClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2128)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1432)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:72)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1843)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.getClassByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1317)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.searchDynamicImports(BundleWiringImpl.java:1558)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1439)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:72)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1843)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.ow2.jonas.lib.loader.OSGiClassLoader.loadClass(OSGiClassLoader.java:87)
        at org.ow2.jonas.lib.loader.OSGiClassLoader.loadClass(OSGiClassLoader.java:96)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
        at org.ow2.jonas.lib.loader.FilteringClassLoader.loadClass(FilteringClassLoader.java:200)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
        at org.ow2.jonas.lib.loader.FilteringClassLoader.loadClass(FilteringClassLoader.java:200)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1663)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1558)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
        at javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:107)
        at javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:166)
        at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:135)
        at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.getInstance(RuntimeDelegate.java:120)
        at javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.valueOf(MediaType.java:179)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.extractMediaTypes(IntrospectionModeller.java:280)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.extractMediaTypes(IntrospectionModeller.java:269)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.resolveProducedTypes(IntrospectionModeller.java:258)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.addResourceMethods(IntrospectionModeller.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.doCreateResourceBuilder(IntrospectionModeller.java:155)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.access$000(IntrospectionModeller.java:80)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller$1.call(IntrospectionModeller.java:111)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller$1.call(IntrospectionModeller.java:108)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.createResourceBuilder(IntrospectionModeller.java:108)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.Resource.from(Resource.java:744)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:404)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:166)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.run(ApplicationHandler.java:327)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:289)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:286)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:286)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:324)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:336)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:170)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:358)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
        at org.ow2.jonas.web.tomcat7.JOnASStandardContext.loadOnStartup(JOnASStandardContext.java:715)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5407)
        at org.ow2.jonas.web.tomcat7.JOnASStandardContext.startInternal(JOnASStandardContext.java:331)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
        at org.ow2.jonas.web.tomcat7.Tomcat7Service.__M_doRegisterWar(Tomcat7Service.java:856)
        at org.ow2.jonas.web.tomcat7.Tomcat7Service.doRegisterWar(Tomcat7Service.java)
        at org.ow2.jonas.web.base.BaseWebContainerService.registerWar(BaseWebContainerService.java:1222)
        at org.ow2.jonas.web.base.BaseWebContainerService.registerWar(BaseWebContainerService.java:1531)
        at org.ow2.jonas.web.base.WARDeployer.doDeploy(WARDeployer.java:78)
        at org.ow2.util.ee.deploy.impl.deployer.AbsDeployer$1.execute(AbsDeployer.java:85)
        at org.ow2.util.ee.deploy.impl.deployer.AbsDeployer$1.execute(AbsDeployer.java:83)
        at org.ow2.util.execution.helper.RunnableHelper.execute(RunnableHelper.java:69)
        at org.ow2.util.ee.deploy.impl.deployer.AbsDeployer.deploy(AbsDeployer.java:83)
        at org.ow2.util.ee.deploy.impl.deployer.AbsDeployerList.deploy(AbsDeployerList.java:44)
        at org.ow2.util.ee.deploy.impl.deployer.AbsDeployer.doDeploy(AbsDeployer.java:225)
        at org.ow2.util.ee.deploy.impl.deployer.AbsDeployer.deploy(AbsDeployer.java:205)
        at org.ow2.util.ee.deploy.impl.deployer.DeployerManager.deployOneTypeList(DeployerManager.java:231)
        at org.ow2.util.ee.deploy.impl.deployer.DeployerManager.doDeploymentOperation(DeployerManager.java:198)
        at org.ow2.util.ee.deploy.impl.deployer.DeployerManager.deploy(DeployerManager.java:212)
        at org.ow2.jonas.deployablemonitor.DeployableMonitor.deploy(DeployableMonitor.java:644)
        at org.ow2.jonas.deployablemonitor.DeployableMonitor.detectNewArchives(DeployableMonitor.java:557)
        at org.ow2.jonas.deployablemonitor.DeployableMonitor.checkNewArchives(DeployableMonitor.java:380)
        at org.ow2.jonas.deployablemonitor.DeployableMonitor.run(DeployableMonitor.java:260)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate not found by org.apache.cxf.bundle [198]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1460)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:72)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1843)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Comment: The class might be in the JAR, but are you sure the JAR is part of the deployed package?  Check that.  Do you have the Maven shade plug-in to create a fat deployable JAR for you?

Comment: i am using Maven to create a war file which i then place in my deploy folder... i am guessing this is what you mean.

Comment: The java class RuntimeDelegate is found WEBINF/lib/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1

Comment: The JAR is in WEB-INF/lib - correct?  The hyphen matters.

Comment: @duffymo yes, i can see the JAR in WEB-INF/lib as javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar

Comment: "I am trying to deploy my REST API on Server": what server are using? And why are you mixing libraries from different vendors (CXF and Jersey)?

Comment: i am using JOnAS v5.3. i googled the error and was trying different things in hopes of solving this issue

Comment: Can you please post the stacktrace. `NoClassDefFoundError` might point to some incorrect configuration too. There will be a caused by in stacktrace which might help.

Comment: @Gautam i posted the stacktrace and found the  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate not found by org.apache.cxf.bundle  not sure where this bundle is

Comment: Why are you using both cxf and jersey?

Comment: @Gautam i am not using cxf, i only added the dependency to try ii as when trying to fix the issue someone said that this dependency will fix it. I think JOnAS has cxf built in i found the jar in  repositories/maven2-internal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl NOT FOUND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452887/org-glassfish-jersey-internal-runtimedelegateimpl-not-found)

Answer (score 2):

Just remove unwanted dependency and add the below dependency in your pom.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

It is tested with **spring-boot.** Indeed, working without any issues at compile time and at runtime also.

Comment: This is right. jersey-common contains the implementation of RuntimeDelegate. You can even make it a <scope>runtime</scope> dependency.