# How to resolve jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl with Jersey on OSGi

Tags: java, jersey, jetty, jax-rs, osgi

Im am using Jersey in an OSGi environment. I wrapped all Jetty and Jersey jars in one bundle containing also my own server / servlet / resource abstraction. This is running quite well. I am importing the javax.ws.rs-api via OSGi package import because related packages are also used by JAX-RS resource implementations in other bundles.

However, from time to time my implementation does not work with an "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl cannot be found by javax.ws.rs-api_2.1.0".

It seems this could be a race condition. Maybe Jersey sometimes uses a class from my internal bundles and sometimes a class from imported javax. I cannot really figure out what the problem is.

The problem is similar to [1], but in my case it is not about any import or dependency. I wrapped the Jetty and Jersey Jars in an OSGi bundle.

[1] [org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl NOT FOUND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452887/org-glassfish-jersey-internal-runtimedelegateimpl-not-found)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl NOT FOUND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452887/org-glassfish-jersey-internal-runtimedelegateimpl-not-found)

Comment: The problem is similar, but in my case it is not about any import or dependency. I wrapped the Jersey Jars in an OSGi bundle.

Comment: I am currently testing: RuntimeDelegate.setInstance(new org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl()). However, I would really like to understand the problem in order to be 100% safe and find the right solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem occurs because the JAX-RS API uses many static methods to get hold of implementation types from the JAX-RS provider. In this case the error isn't coming from Jersey, but actually from the JAX-RS API itself when it tries to find an implementation of the various JAX-RS interfaces.

You effectively have four options:

- Avoid exposing the JAX-RS API from your server by putting all the resources in there as well *(I don't recommend this option!)*
- Embed the JAX-RS API in your existing Jetty/Jersey uber bundle and export it from there. Be careful to include the correct API package versions and contract capabilities! *(This option is fiddly)*
- Use an OSGi-aware API bundle (such as one from Apache Aries, Apache Geronimo or Apache Service Mix). Many Java EE API bundles (JAX-RS included) package themselves as OSGi bundles, but ignore the fact that they actually need to work in OSGi, which means that you can't rely on reflectively loading types/resources from a flat classpath. *(This option is probably quickest and lets you keep working as you are)*
- Move to using the new OSGi JAX-RS whiteboard from OSGi Release 7. The reference implementation for this is in Apache Aries and [available on GitHub](https://github.com/apache/aries-jax-rs-whiteboard) *(This is the best long term option from an OSGi perspective, and means that you can avoid maintaining your own server)*

I hope this all makes sense, explains why you're seeing the error, and hopefully gives you some options for working through the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and options! Currently I don't have the error anymore using "RuntimeDelegate.setInstance(new org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl())" in my startup phase of the server bundle. Could this also be a potential solution? What is different to the re-packaged API bundle. I am already using javax.ws.rs-api_2.1.0 and it seems to be OSGi-aware. It is added to the target platform and packages are included by my server bundle.

Comment: I can't identify any specific changes in the aries API bundle compared to the original API bundle (option three): https://github.com/apache/aries-jax-rs-whiteboard/tree/master/javax.jax.rs-api

Comment: Setting an explicit RuntimeDelegate will work, but isn't a very modular solution (different implementations can fight with one another, and there are potential ordering issues). Also for the extra metadata - there's a big Provide-Capability section added (see https://github.com/apache/aries-jax-rs-whiteboard/blob/c62794dfaf5fab8e95e03815c6176bdcf9fa763e/javax.jax.rs-api/bnd.bnd#L5-L9)